# Compressing data with GZipStream in C# and upload it to a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have an XML data which I would like to compress it using GZipStream and upload it to webservice. I would like to create the gzip file in memory instead of of creating it in local disk. I have tried the following:

```
public string class1(string url, string xml)
{
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
                    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
                    GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress, true);                    
                    gzip.Write(data, 0, data.Length);                       
                    byte[] zip=memory.ToArray();

HttpWebRequest wReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    wReq.Method = "POST";
                    wReq.ContentType = "application/zip";
                    var reqStream = wReq.GetRequestStream();
                    reqStream.Write(zip,0,zip.Length);
                    reqStream.Close();

                    var wRes = wReq.GetResponse();
                    var resStream = wRes.GetResponseStream();
                    var resgzip = new GZipStream(resStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                    var reader = new StreamReader(resgzip);
                    var textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                    resStream.Close();
                    wRes.Close();
                    return textResponse;
}
```

After writing data to webservice the server unzips the file and processess it. While the server decompresses the data an exception is thrown in server "Premature end of file". Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Add below method to convert Stream to MemoryStream

```
 public static MemoryStream Read(Stream stream)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        memStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    return memStream;
}
```

then call as below.

```
var wRes = wReq.GetResponse();                    
var memstream = Read(wRes.GetResponseStream()); 

var resgzip = new GZipStream(memstream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
var reader = new StreamReader(resgzip);
var textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: The decompression of response from server works fine. The issue here is compressing the xml data which I have as a string to gzipstream and sending it to server.

Comment: try this may be useful `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memstream.ToArray());`